# Stepper motor with microstep driver

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, stepper

In my project I have to control a stepper motor using arduino and microstep driver, can I control the motor so that it can move 90 degrees then stop for like a second and then move again and repeat that sequence.
Can I do that please help I'm stuck in the code and I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: In what code are you stuck? You didn't provide any in your question. If you already have a code, then include it in the question. If not: Have you tried the examples with one of the Arduino stepper libraries (like `Stepper` or `Accelstepper`)? Have you tried to understand how they work? If you have problems understanding them: What exactly gives you problems here? We need more information to provide good answers.

Comment: Yes I tried with a bunch of code this one work the best for my stepper: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Esu1wzS0HfXB_lRHbog6yM09OSJ5SSu/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can! There are some excellent libraries to control steppers, e.g. [Stepper](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Stepper) or [AccelStepper](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/).

What you describe sounds like basic task that is covered in examples of these libraries. For example, this one: https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Stepper/blob/master/examples/stepper_oneRevolution/stepper_oneRevolution.ino. You only need to set correct pins and tweak delays and rotation angles (if your stepper has 200 steps per revolution, then 90 degrees is 50 steps).

Comment: This code is working well for me what could I change to get the motion needed https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Esu1wzS0HfXB_lRHbog6yM09OSJ5SSu/view

Comment: What to do with that particular code is a whole different question to what was initially asked. That said, your code looks fine, it probably does 2 revolutions continuously (depends on motor). To change that to 90 deg with pause, change 400 to 50 and add `delay(1000);` to `loop`. Also, as others noted, you need to understand your code to make it work, there is no other way.

Comment: Thanks I understand it now and It's working. I'm a beginner when it comes to programming, I tried a lot of codes from AccelStepper and other libraries none has worked for me so, I was frustrated and I wrote the question in a hurry. sorry for that and thank you again for the help.